# Databricks - How to change a partition of an existing Delta table via table path?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, delta-lake

I want to use this syntax that was posted in a similar thread to update the partitions of a delta table I have.  The challenge is the delta table does not exist in databricks but we use databricks to update the delta able via Azure Data factory.

How can I adjust the below syntax to update the partitions and overwrite the table via the table path?

Python:

```
val input = spark.read.table("mytable")

input.write.format("delta")
  .mode("overwrite")
  .option("overwriteSchema", "true")
  .partitionBy("colB") // different column
  .saveAsTable("mytable")



SQL:
REPLACE TABLE <tablename>
  USING DELTA
  PARTITIONED BY (view_date)
AS
 SELECT * FROM <tablename>
```

I tried to adjust the above code but could not adjust it to use the delta table path.

Answer (score 1):

If you have path, then you need to use correct functions:

- for Python, you need to use `.load` for reading, and `.save` for writing
- if you're using SQL, then you specify table as following:

```
delta.`path`
```